# Why did Zobrist leave the trail to the virus in the first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, inferno

So the billionaire in *Inferno* leaves a crumb trail all the way to the inferno virus so his followers can find it e.g. Siena. And Siena even says she's going to protect the virus to ensure it goes off because people are looking for it. However, the people looking for it are only able to find it, as is Siena, because of the trail Zobrist left.

Why did he leave a crumb trail? It doesn't make sense. Nobody would have found it if he didn't. Just time the device to go off. Most likely, the WHO characters in the film wouldn't have even known without the Faraday pointer...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Zobrist leaves a trail as to give "the world a chance", so as to prove his point that not many can solve it. If you really want to understand the movie, go read the book.

Comment: Imo, I shouldn't have to read a book to understand a movie. I don't believe his motives were ever fully given during the movie. Except that he was a radical and really believed in his cause.

Comment: Reading the book will not help you understand the film. It will only make it worse.